# Allow powershell script to run after marking it with "never run"

Tags: powershell

I ran `Set-ExecutionPolicy` to `AllSigned`, and when I try to run my script, on the prompt to trust the publisher, I accidentally entered V, to never run the script.

How do I undo this, so that I can run the script again without changing the execution policy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the cert you deauthorized was added to the untrusted certificates in your cert store.

- Load mmc and the Certificates snap-in
- Manage certs  for My user Account
- Browse to the Untrusted Certs
- Remove the good cert from the list